# How do I add FigureCanvasQTAgg in a pyqt layout?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have an issue when I add a matplotlib figure into a pyqt5 environment.

I get this error :

```
  File "C:\Users\maxime\Desktop\SESAME\PycharmProjects\neocom\di.py", line 37, in __init__
    layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
TypeError: addWidget(self, a0: QWidget, stretch: int = 0, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'FigureCanvasQTAgg'
```

I don't understand this error because every post I saw do the same thing to add the figure.
Where did I go wrong?
It is like FigureCanvasQTAgg  is not a widget but it should be, right?

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QHBoxLayout()
        V1 = Viewer()
 
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(V1)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)


class Viewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super( Viewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.axes_Delay = self.figure.add_subplot(1, 1,1)
        self.axes_Delay.set_title("Title")

        # self.canvas.setGeometry(0, 0, 1600, 500 )
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.canvas.show()
 
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = window(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same exact problem in a integration between PyQt6 and MatPlotLib till I found this new command:

```
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

immediately after:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Also, I found that is better to have:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
```

instead of:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
```

To me it seems there nothing wrong with your code, seems only a bug due to different version and integrations between MatPlotLib and PyQt (with PyQt6 there is no way to make it work, at least for me). The default config in matplotlib.use() is not really clear on the documentation (https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html).

Hope this helps!